# how to pass variable through model.matrix() in r

Tags: r, model.matrix

I'm creating a function that performs cross-validation and ridge regression to select predictors for a model. The inputs of my function are `dataframe` and the desired outcome variable `outcome` (what is being predicted). I'm using model.matrix() to create an x matrix that I will pass to glmnet(). My function uses `outcome` as the object argument in model.matrix(), but it looks like `outcome` is the wrong data type to pass through model.matrix(). Using model.matrix() normally, I would write something like `model.matrix(Weight~.,dataframe)`. In this case, however, model.matrix won't work as `model.matrix(outcome~.,dataframe)` or `model.matrix(dataframe$outcome~.,dataframe)`. Any ideas?

Comment: You may use `paste` with `formula` i.e. `model.matrix(formula(paste(outcome, "~ .")), dataframe)`

Comment: It would help if you could share a small reproducible example, or at least tell us what class the mysterious `outcome` variable is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'outcome' is the object that stores the string `"Weight"`, then we can `paste` with `formula`

```
model.matrix(formula(paste(outcome, "~ .")), dataframe)
```

A reproducible example with 'iris' dataset

```
data(iris)
outcome <- "Species"
m1 <-  model.matrix(formula(paste(outcome, "~ .")), iris)
m2 <- model.matrix(Species ~ ., iris)
identical(m1, m2)
#[1] TRUE
```